# Oracle Apex insert data into OCI bucket

Tags: oracle-apex, bucket, object-storage, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Hey every one I need a help, I have a OCI account and in my oracle apex I want to store the data into my OCI Object Storage Bucket, is there a way to store the data in the OCI Bucket Can anyone suggest a way to store and access the data in the oracle apex.

Answer (score 0):

Using Object Storage for data/backup storage is an efficient practice to reduce workload on your Database. You can easily create, fetch and delete files of all sizes using PL/SQL and APEX.

For this I found this [very helpful document](https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/-using-oracle-storage-cloud-service-for-apex-blobs) which shall get you up to speed to implement the REST API.